# Managing database content on jhipster server

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jhipster

How would one go about managing the data in their PostgreSQL database on their JHipster generated server? My goal is to be able to periodically check the items in the database and perform certain tasks based on the database contents.

I'm new to using JHipster and I'm not sure how I'd go about adding or removing entities as well as adding items to entities on the server. I understand that services facilitate doing these operations for the client-side, but I can't see how I would use the same approach to do what I need on the server (if this is even the correct approach).

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, are you a beginner in software development? JHipster generates a user interface (client side) to manage your database content on top of a REST API and JPA (server side), it defines 2 user roles (user and administrator)  it's up to you to modify the generated code to fit your needs.

Comment: Hi, I'm not new to software development, I'm only new to using the Spring framework as well as JHipster. My goal is to manage the database directly on the server. My understanding is that modifying the generated code only provides functionality that can be used by the client-side.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong.  The generated code can be used by any external client consuming the REST API, one of these clients is the generated UI (in Angular, React or Vue) but you can write others (e.g. a mobile app) and also you can write pure server-side processing like scheduled batches. What backend framework have you already used? Maybe I can explain with analogy. You should edit your question to add more details about what you want to do because it will be closed otherwise

Comment: Oh, thank you I see now. I haven't used a backend framework before unfortunately. I've updated my question to include my target use-case, and based on your comment, can I use scheduled batches to do this?

Comment: I answered but I think you should invest time to learn about Spring and JPA because JHipster generates advanced code and you'll get lost very quickly if you don't know about the technology stack it uses. Your question is in fact not about JHipster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To schedule a task on backend you can annotate a **public** method of a service with `@Scheduled`, you can find an example in the code generated by JHipster in `UserService`  class look at the `removeNotActivatedUsers()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand now that I was trying to schedule a task in one of my services that would use the service's corresponding repository to manage the entity.